# Trying to pass params in to a modal using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

i have a page(products.php) that has a table which is dynamically populated. Each row has a button that opens up a modal, but in order to pass params to the modal: firstly, i declared the modal on the current page(products.php). Secondly, i call up the rest of the modal using ajax from another page(modal.php). i've popuplated all options in a select drop down before using ajax,  but i can't seem to do the same this time by displaying the modal. i can use php href but that causes my jquery script that i use in submitting to the database on my modal not to work anymore and that's why i thought up doing this through ajax. I would like to know why this isn't working with well ajax.

Heres a sample code:

products.php

```
    <html>
    <header>
    <script>
        function modalValues(val1,val2){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

         xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        }else{

         xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("load_here").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhhtp.open("POST","modal.php?id3="+val1+"&id="+val2,true);
        xhttp.send();
        }
     </script>
    </header>

    <body>

    <div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false"  id="product_customerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="product_customerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div id="load_here" class="modal-content">
</div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <table>
    <?php
    global $link;

    $query = "blah,blah";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    $number = mysqli_num_rows($result_set);

    for($count=0;$count<$number;$count++){
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$result['field1']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$result['field2']}</td>";
    echo "<td><button onclick='modalValues(<?php echo $result['field1'];?>,<?php echo $result['field2'];?>) data-toggle="modal" data-target='#product_customerModal'></button></td>";
    }
    ?>

    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And

modal.php

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
       <h4 class="modal-title" >    Date: (<?php echo $date;?>)</h4></div
    <div class="modal-body">
<?php
//some php code
?>
    <div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct two lines they are as follows and then your model html will be there:
`xhttp.open("POST","test2.php?id3="+val1+"&id="+val2,true);` not xhttp

`echo "<td><button onclick='modalValues('".$result['field1']."','".$result['field2']."') data-toggle='modal' data-target='#product_customerModal'></button></td>";`